# Problema con RecyclerView y Lista en Android

Tags: android, recyclerview, nullpointerexception

Buenas.

Estoy intentando descargar una serie de datos de internet. Para ello, mediante un webservice lleno una lista de objetos. Esta lista la envío al `RecycleAdapter` para que las muestre en el `RecyclerView`. Pero al hacerlo, me sale este problema.

[image: Error]

El caso es que esa lista SI esta llena, y no se que puede pasar. La linea donde dice que esta el error es aqui.

[image]

Otra cosa curiosa, es que cuando inicio la aplicación, al principio si empieza a mostrar la lista, pero al segundo y poco desaparece y crashea mostrando el error que os he enseñado antes.

AÑADO:

```
public void cargarBatallas(){
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        RecyclerView rviewtimeline = (RecyclerView)this.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rviewtimeline.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        //sTextView txtEmpty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emptyTimeline);
        //listTimeLine.setEmptyView(txtEmpty);
        List<Batalla> batallaList = new ArrayList<Batalla>();
        BatallasRecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new BatallasRecyclerAdapter(batallaList);
        rviewtimeline.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        GetBatallas getAsync = new GetBatallas(this, key_session, rviewtimeline , GetBatallas.GET_TIMELINE, null, recyclerAdapter);
        getAsync.execute();
    }
```

OnPostExecute (Despues de descargar datos y llenar list)

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Log.d(msg, "probando");

    if(batallaList != null){
        Log.d(msg, "probando1");

        adapterRecycler.setData(batallaList);
        adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();}}
```

Clase Adapter:

```
public class BatallasRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BatallasRecyclerAdapter.BatallaViewHolder>{


    List<Batalla> listBatalla;

    public BatallasRecyclerAdapter(List<Batalla> listBatalla){
        this.listBatalla = listBatalla;
    }

    public void setData(List<Batalla> listBatalla){
        this.listBatalla = listBatalla;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listBatalla.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BatallaViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewHolder.txtUsuario1.setText(listBatalla.get(position).getUsuario1());
        viewHolder.txtUsuario2.setText(listBatalla.get(position).getUsuario2());
    }

    @Override
    public BatallaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.molde_lista, parent, false);
        BatallaViewHolder holder = new BatallaViewHolder(v); 
        return holder;
    }

    public static class BatallaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtUsuario1;
        TextView txtUsuario2;
        public BatallaViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            txtUsuario1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario1);
            txtUsuario2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsuario2);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: HOla kike, acostumbra agregar texto a tu pregunta no imagenes de characters, agrega la parte donde llamas BatallasRecyclerAdapter.setData()...

Comment: Hola Jorge, a partir de ahora utilizaré el texto, soy nuevo en esta platafaforma. ¡Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso el problema es que la clase `BatallasRecyclerAdapter` no esta instanciada correctamente, al llamar el mètodo `setData()` marca error ya que la instancia tiene valor null.

Este es un ejemplo, pero necesitas agregar la clase porque probablemente reciba valores para inicializaciòn.

```
BatallasRecyclerAdapter RecycleAdapter = new BatallasRecyclerAdapter();
```

El código correcto para inicializar serìa:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    Log.d(msg, "probando");

    if(batallaList != null){
        Log.d(msg, "probando1");
        adapterRecycler = new BatallasRecyclerAdapter(batallaList);
        //adapterRecycler.setData(batallaList);
        adapterRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas ya he subido información sobre la instancia!

Comment: Gracias ya vì, el error es provocado por lo que comento, pero como se llama tu clase Adapter, es BatallasRecyclerAdapter ? si es asì serìa bueno agregarla para comentar como instanciarla correctamente.

Comment: Mi clase adapter ya la he agregado en la imagen, pero vuelvo a agregarla.

Comment: Acabo de agregarla, y en efecto, se llama así: "BatallasRecyclerAdapter". Yo aun no he detectado el error...

Comment: He actualizado, en realidad al instanciar defines los datos en el Adapter, probablemente necesites inicializar al iniciar tu Asynctask.

Comment: Ahora no me da error de crash... Pero no me carga los datos en el recyclerview

Comment: Donde haces setAdapter() de adapterRecycler ?

Comment: He incluido el setAdapter() despues del notifyDataChanged() y me ha vuelto a dar el mismo error del principio, pero ahora me da como null el setAdapter().

Comment: Siempre debe ser setAdapter()  antes de notifyDataChanged()

Comment: He puesto el setAdapter() antes e igual.

Comment: Agrega tu clase completa se supone que setAdapter se relaciona al ListView, donde esta el ListView, en el Asynctask o se encuentra en otra clase? Te recomiendo agregar la clase del ASynctask y donde se encuentra el ListView.

Comment: ¡YA LO HE SOLUCIONADO! Vaya una tarde me ha dado esto. Ahora subo la solución. He instanciado al RecyclerView y al Adaptador desde el mismo sitio y ya funcionaba bien.

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias Jorge por tu ayuda! Un saludo. @Jorgesys

Comment: un placer saludos.